# SqlCE as a DB under asp.net - what are the disadvantages?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-ce

I can't buy a the SQL server full/express plan on my hosting environment and I was thinking of using  SQLCE with EF 4.0
expected user load is 1000-2000 per day.

Comment: Is that the number of visitors a day (so 1000-2000 * page requests) or the number of pages requests a day? Also, how often does the data change? This can be addressed with caching of certain pages etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"user load is 1000-2000 per day"

This isn't a particularly good measure of what load your database will be under. 
You need to measure things like:

- the number and complexity of your queries.
- What kind of writes (insert/update/delete) will need to be performed.
- How many of those a user might perform.
- The amount of data being dealt with in the above queries.
- Whether you can cache any of the results of queries.

For instance, I know of systems where having 1000 users required a cluster of high end servers to deal with the load.

If you can model what the performance is like for 50, 100, and 500 users - that could give you an idea of whether you can deal with this load.

FWIW: SQL Server Express Edition is free for commercial usage.

Answer (score 0):

The sqlserverCe-dll (as well as the similar SQLite-dll) has 32bit native code inside. so there might be some 32/64bit issues when running on a 64bit system.

I am not shure if there is already a 64bit sqlserverCe-dll.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Compact will run under medium trust under ASP.NET 4, and supports both x64 and x86 platforms. It is limited to max 256 concurrent connections. It is file based, and not quite as robust as SQL Server, and does not support recovery to a point in time.